# Windows 8 Store app, Type.IsClass and System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool missing

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps

I am investigating Windows 8 Store app development, and am having trouble locating the following members

Type.IsClass

System.ComponentModel.DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool

Visual studio claims they don't exist, but MSDN suggests they should.

I am obviously missing something silly: Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Regards

John.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`IsClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.type.isclass.aspx) property has moved to the [`TypeInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.reflection.typeinfo.aspx) class. Basically you need to replace;

```
bool result = type.IsClass;
```

with;

```
bool result = type.GetTypeInfo().IsClass;
```

[`GetTypeInfo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.reflection.introspectionextensions.gettypeinfo.aspx) is an extension method from the System.Reflection namespace, no not obviously visible on System.Type unless you're already `using System.Reflection`.

The `IsInDesignTool` property has [moved to another place too and changed name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.designmode.designmodeenabled.aspx);

```
bool result = Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled;
```